# Audio Issue: YouTube not playing background music

Tags: windows, youtube, acer-aspire

I've got an audio issue where YouTube videos are playing with the background music and noise removed, leaving only the speakers' voices audible. My device is a Windows laptop with RealTek audio. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me:

1. In Windows, go to Settings > System > Sound > Speakers.
2. Find *Audio enhancements*, and turn it off.

I hope this solution helps others who might be experiencing the same issue.

Comment: A better option, go into RealTek audio config panel, and disable karaoke there.